# Capture messages in from python-shell in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, electron, console.log

I am new to `Javascript` but am attempting to build an `Electron` app as a gui to a `python` script.

I am using [python-shell](https://www.npmjs.com/package/python-shell) to call my `Python` script and can successfully do this and printing the output in the console. However I would like to capture multiple `Python` print statements in a `Javascript` array.

Following the [python-shell](https://www.npmjs.com/package/python-shell) docs I can access each `Python` print statement via the `message` event.

```
    var res = [];

    var ligation = PythonShell.run("ligation.py", options, function (err, results) {
          if (err) throw err;
          // console.log('results: %j', results);
        });

    ligation.on('message', function(message) {
        // console.log(message)
        res.push(message)
    })

    console.log(res)
```

However when I try to assign the ouput of these events to an array it works but I cannot access the values as the console looks like this:

[image]

where the 8 numbers are my output. When I try to access a single value (e.g. `console.log(res[0])`) I get it reported that it is undefined.

I gather that the little blue i means that the values are just evaluated and figure this may have something to do with it but I do not know what.

I figure there must be something straightforward I am missing. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The console output does indeed look awkward, try moving `console.log(res)` inside the event listener, in other words, log `res` every time a new message is received.

Comment: When I put the `console.log(res)` in the function of `ligation.on` I get 8 console_logs with arrays of length 1 to 8. The final array is what I am trying to get but I don't know how to assign this to a global variable that I can use outside that function.

Comment: It looks like the easiest way to solve this would be to alter my python script so that it only prints once resulting in a single string. I could then split that string into an array in `Javascript` and do all the code in the event listener.

Comment: If that's what's happening then it's pretty logical. The first console message is in the initial state of the array, empty. Then every time a message is received, the array is mutated with the new item added to it. Try sending multiple messages, then open up your console using `F12` (since you're using Chrome) and write `res`. You should see that your array is exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Best would be to put logic or call your function from onmessage event - checking global variable out of event call scope is not good idea - very hard to synchronize if run method is async.